# Rails undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass...but it is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

I have searched for hours, tried every possible fix. I cannot make this work. The error is:

```
  *NoMethodError in Articles#index
  Showing /Users/myname/blog/app/views/articles/showall.html.erb where     line #21 raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass*
```

showall.html.erb is a view. It is rendered from the 'article' controller. (both posted below). There is a route to showall, and it works fine. Currently the route is configured as:

```
get 'article/showall'
```

But, I have also tried it as:

```
resources :articles do
  get 'showall'
resources :comments
```

Both routes worked, but neither had an effect on the issue.

There is a method in the controller, its not private:

```
def showall
   @articles = Article.all
end
```

The offending piece of code in the view is:

```
 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= article.title.truncate(30) %></td>
  <td><%= article.author %></td>
  <td><%= article.manufacturer %></td>
  <td><%= article.model %></td>
  <td><%= article.displacement %></td>`

<% end %>
```

I actually cut and pasted, the piece of code from the index.html.erb view, where it works perfectly. I have tried every nuance of pluralization I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This applicable parts of the controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:index, :show, :showall]

 #Filter used to catch nonlogged in users 
 before_filter :require_user, :only => [:index]

#method that checks if logged in, sends them to showall if not.
def require_user
unless User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  render 'showall', :notice => "Please log in to read articles."
end
end

def index

@articles = current_user.articles

end

#should list articles, but throws undefined method 'each' error
def showall
@articles = Article.all
end
```

Here is the entire view:

```
 <%= render "menu" %>

 <body>
 <font color="yellow"><%= flash[:notice] %></font>
 <br>
 <font color="grey">Motorcycle Articles</font>
 <%= link_to 'Post New Article', new_article_path %> 
 <br>

 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>Title</th>

 <th>Author</th>
 <th>Brand</th>
 <th>Model</th>
 <th>Displacment</th>
 <th>Last Edited On:</th>
 <th>Article</th>
 </tr>
 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= article.title.truncate(30) %></td>
  <td><%= article.author %></td>
  <td><%= article.manufacturer %></td>
  <td><%= article.model %></td>
  <td><%= article.displacement %></td>

  <% end %>
  </table>
  <br>
   All articles are property of their respective owners.

 </body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have some articles saved in database?

Comment: yes, I can list them with index.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling render 'showall', which renders the view. This is different than 'redirect_to', which calls the controller action. Since you are setting the value of @articles with a nil value (current_user is not set), you get this error.

To clarify, you need to either redirect_to the 'showall' action or redefine @articles to equal Article.all before rendering the view.  Personally I'd redirect.

Comment: If I change 'render' to 'redirect_to', it comes back with `Routing Error, uninitialized constant ArticleController`, and shows the routing table. If I change it to `redirect_to article_showall_path`, I get the same result.

Comment: If I change the route to `resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  get 'showall'  
  end`, I get a different error: No route matches [GET] "/article/showall". Yet right below the error in the routing table is `article_showall_path GET /articles/:article_id/showall(.:format) articles#showall`

Comment: Specifying the route with a plural "articles" ie GET "articles/showall", to: Articles#showall before calling :resources should correct the routing issue. From there you could either call the path with the redirect_to, or simply call the controller action (ie redirect_to action: "showall") will do the trick.  Incidentally,  if the view in your index is exactly the same, you could skip the new action entirely and simply redirect there, adding a container for any alerts/notifications.

Comment: I did decide to abandon this approach and simply add some logic in the index view to determine what individuals see depending on their credentials. I clearly need to go back and study how a before filter works. Thank you for the input.

Comment: From here it looks like you were using the before_filter correctly, just some minor semantics with the routing and the redirect.  But if you can condense the action into the index with some minor logic, I would think that will be more maintainable in the long run, and a more DRY solution anyhow. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Route is triggering index action, see:

```
NoMethodError in Articles#index
```

You get the error because `current_user.articles` is nil.

You need to make sure `Articles#showall` is appearing in the log, that will mean that `showall` method is called.

Do that creating routes:

```
get '/articles', to: 'Articles#showall'
resources :articles
```

This is not recommended. There are several parts to improve. But it should make the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `routes` file

routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  collection do
    get 'showall'
  end
end
```

Comment: This results in a routing error `No route matches [GET] "/article/showall"`. Confusing, because rake routes shows `article_showall_path GET /articles/:article_id/showall(.:format) articles#showall`